# Grouping Ordered items in Sales->Order View

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, group

Where and what do I need to adjust to group this based on the first word of the Product Name?

So that If ever I placed an order again using WORD IPHONE it will be under the 3rd line which is iphone.

[image]

Comment: instead of grouping why not use sorting for product name?

Comment: Good Point. Thanks. Can  you assist me on where can I adjust it or what file should I adjust, got stuck for days for just this one. Thanks